# Why won't the change event handler work with my code?

Tags: jquery, events, onchange

My script below detects when a key is pressed on a certain text input.  The problem with this method is that it also detects when keys like shift and control and even escape are pressed.  I only want my ajax script to execute when the text input is actually changed.  Like I said, on('keydown', function()) works, but on('change', function()) won't do anything when I type in the field.  Not sure what's going on here.

```
$(document).on('change', '[rel^="liveSearch"]', function () {

            console.log('key pressed');
            if($(this).length >= 3){

                var fieldName = $(this).prop("name");
                var searchMenu = $('#liveSearch');

                $.ajax({
                    url: searchMenu.data('ajax-url')+'/'+$('input[name="'+fieldName+'"]').val(),
                    dataType: "xml",
                    statusCode: {
                        404: function(){alert("404 not found!")}
                    }
                })
                .done(function(xml){
                    if($(xml).find('member').length > 0){
                        $(xml).find('member').each(function(){
                            var memberId = $(this).attr("mid");
                            var memberName = $(this).find('displayname').text();
                            searchMenu.html('<li onclick="appendValue(\''+fieldName+'\', \''+memberId+'\');hideMenu(\''+searchMenu+'\');">'+memberName+'</li>');
                            searchMenu.show();
                        });
                    } else {
                        searchMenu.html('');
                        searchMenu.hide();
                    }
                });                 

            }

});
```

Comment: The on change event seems to fire only when the text input looses focus, [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpPsc/), my suggestion would be to blacklist the unwanted keys and return false.

Comment: I thought that's what "blur()" was for...

Comment: Use `keypress` instead of `keydown` and you shouldn't get events for special keys.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Blur fires when you leave the field even if you didn't change anything. Change only fires if it has been edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `change` event doesn't fire on a text input field until you leave it.

To detect when real character keys have been typed into the input, use the `keypress` event instead of `keydown`.

Answer (score 0):

Remember previous value of the input field. You can store it in a data attribute. Then on keydown compare two values and do ajax request only if they are not matching. This way you will avoid hitting server if data has not changed.

Comment: Data attributes are not meant to handle dynamic data.

Comment: You can use jQuery's `.data()` method. It reads initially from data attributes, but doesn't use them for storage.